# Apache2 vhost SSL configuration running on Plesk

Tags: apache, https, plesk

I  have a problem with configuring ssl in apache 2 vhost configuration running plesk.
My Server is running on a virtual machine with plesk 12.

And basically I just want to setup ssl for the domain.

I know there is a plugin espacially for this but I also need an ssl certificate for my mongodb so i thought it would be good to use the same cert for both of these.

In the file "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.de/conf/httpd.conf"
Is the line Include

```
"/var/www/vhosts/system/example.de/conf/vhost_ssl.conf"
```

So I believe in can configure stuff in the vhost_ssl.conf file

This is my vhost_ssl.conf file:

```
SLEngine on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/fullchain.pem
```

But when i try to reconfigure my domain i get this Error:

```
ERR [util_exec] proc_close() failed ['/opt/psa/admin/bin/apache_control_adapter' '--restart' '--restart-interval' '0' '--http-port' '7080' '--https-port' '7081'] with exit code [255] 
ERR [panel] Apache config (14588122890.93280300) generation failed: Template_Exception: Can not restart web server: Service /etc/init.d/apache2 failed to start
Service /etc/init.d/apache2 failed to start

file: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Service/Driver/Web/Server/Apache.php
line: 110
code: 0
Can not restart web server: Service /etc/init.d/apache2 failed to start
Service /etc/init.d/apache2 failed to start
```

So I believe there is something wrong with my Configuration :(

I'm pretty new in this whole self hosting stuff, but parse will be shut down so I need to host the stuff by myself.

I'm already pretty sure that this is some noob question but I cannot find any solution in the web.

Comment: Server Fault participants are much more likely to know the technical details on topics such as DNS and Apache configuration than people who answer questions here.